# Background-color not changing by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery on my webpage.
I am changing background color of a div.
Its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $("#gridbox").css({'background-color':'black'});​
    </script>
```

Comment: I think it's $("#gridbox").css({'background-color','black'}); - comma not colon​

Comment: @Onheiron: no, the colon is correct. Note its in curly brackets so its not comma separated parameters, its properties being set (JSON style).

Comment: @Onheiron You're getting confused with `$("#gridbox").css('background-color','black');`

Comment: <div id="gridbox">
                    <div class="friend cell">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="name">Bob</span>
                            <br />
                            (id: 57)
                            <input type="hidden" class="friend_id" value="57 " />
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>

Comment: Can you provide the html and the css you used with this jquery code please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should work, try using document ready handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#gridbox").css({'background-color':'black'});​
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WcQse/

Answer (score 4):

Its possible your script is running before the DOM has loaded. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#gridbox").css({'background-color':'black'});​
     });
</script>
```

[-- Demo --](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7gPE/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

If you are using `ASP.NET` then your `Client ID` might change depending on the use of `Master Pages` in that case you can try something like this.

```
  $('#<%= gridbox.ClientID %>' ).css('background-color','black');​
```

If it is just a `div` then you should wrap it in `document.ready()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#gridbox').css('background-color','black');

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQub4/2/)**

Comment: @freebird: there is no indication of the serverside language being used so you should at least explain that this answer is only valid for ASP.NET or something. It might be plain HTML, php or any number of other things...

Answer (score 1):

The same code that you are using is working fine for me

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="gridbox" style="background-color:red;">gridbox</div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#gridbox").css({'background-color':'black'});
         </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

so you should first include the jquery library, then put the javascript file after the div that you want to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#gridbox").css("background-color", "black");
```

Edit:

Add a document ready function, this will execute the css change after the `DOM` has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#gridbox").css("background-color", "black");
});
```

Note: Ensure you have the jQuery JavaScript file referenced in the page.

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){
    ​$(".gridbox").css('background-color','red');
    });

now i made it class but still same problem

Comment: @HHF - does the element have the gridbox class applied to it? It should work.  Do you have the reference to the jQuery file?

Comment: @HHF Post your entire markup , we cannot tell what exactly is missing unless you provide more information.